# Finding a modules position in Opencart 2

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to get a modules position so that I can alter the template based on where it is being placed. I used to check the `$setting['position']` from inside the controller and then pass that to the view, but as positioning of modules is being done through the layout manager, that property is no longer available.

This is what works in Opencart 1.5.6 -

```
// Module Controller
$this->data['position'] = $setting['position'];

// Module View
<?php if ($position === "content_top" or $position === "content_bottom") { ?>
    <!-- position specific markup -->
<?php } ?>
```

How can the same thing be achieved in Opencart 2?

Comment: I haven't yet had time to cope with OC 2 but looked at the whole system how modules are loaded, instantiated etc., and can say, that it looks like impossible without a rather huge core system modification... I could tell you more or be more accurate after I install it and play around a little with it...

Comment: has been change feature for Module position in OC 2. So, I think, You need to set your code according to OC 2.0. See this for set Module position in OC 2 - http://www.harnishdesign.net/blog/2014/10/09/how-to-set-layout-position-of-module-in-opencart-2-0/

Comment: @HarnishDesign that explains settings a modules position, but it doesn't explain finding a module position from the controller

Answer (score 1):

In previous we use to set `position(content_top/content_bottom)` in module page (extension/module) for particular module

Now in Opencart 2.0 we set `position(content_top/content_bottom)` and module in particular layout page (system/design/layout)

That is the reason you don't have `$setting['position'];` in module's Controller.

if you want just use this code with desired `position(content_top/content_bottom)` in desired controller.

```
$this->load->model('design/layout');

if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
 $route = (string)$this->request->get['route'];
} else {
 $route = 'common/home';
}

$layout_id = 0;

if ($route == 'product/category' && isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
 $path = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);

 $layout_id = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoryLayoutId(end($path));
}

if ($route == 'product/product' && isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
 $layout_id = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductLayoutId($this->request->get['product_id']);
}

if ($route == 'information/information' && isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
 $layout_id = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformationLayoutId($this->request->get['information_id']);
}

if (!$layout_id) {
 $layout_id = $this->model_design_layout->getLayout($route);
}

if (!$layout_id) {
 $layout_id = $this->config->get('config_layout_id');
}

$data['modules'] = array();

$modules = $this->model_design_layout->getLayoutModules($layout_id, 'content_top');
```

It will return the module assigned to `content_top`

Comment: This will only return the names of all modules which are there on a specific layout and on specific position, it doesn't tell on which position is the module applied currently.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative method, I had the same problem while converting some of my modules to work with Opencart 2. I did it on client side with jQuery. I JSON encoded my module data and in tpl did the following:

```
<div id="my_module_<?php echo $module; ?>"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var data_json = '<?php echo $my_module_json; ?>';
var data = $.parseJSON(data_json);
var target = $('#my_module_<?php echo $module; ?>');

var position = '';
if ($(target).closest('#column-left').length){
  position = 'column-left';
}
else if ($(target).closest('#column-right').length){
  position = 'column-right'; 
}
else{
  position = 'content'; 
}

var html = '';

if (position == 'content') {
  $html +='HTML for content position';
  // ... do whatever
}
else
{
  $html +='HTML for column position';
  // ... do something else
}

$(target).html(html);
</script>
```

seems to work alright.